# Order Emails are not generated :: SMTP configurations required :: Magento community open source

Tags: magento2, sales-order, magento2.3, order-email, magento2.3.1

- Magento 2.3.1
- PaymentGateway: Fatzebra
- OS: Ubuntu 18.04
- Environment: Dev

I have used following code from here: https://magecomp.com/blog/send-order-confirmation-email-after-successful-payment-magento-2/

I have also tried to make it work by disabling store->configuration->Sales->Sales Email->Order to No/yes both options but still not working.

Any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out smtp needed to be configured . Since magento community doesn't come with proper smtp configurations (stores->configuration->Advanced->system->Mail Sending Settings) so I sued MagePal free extension. There is also another smtp extension by mageplaza but for me its not working with my magento version 2.3.1. Although Mageplaza says its compatible with magento 2.3 as per this link

> https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-smtp/issues/129

Hence use MagePal or MagePlaza extension whichever works for your magento version. According to following link mageplaza works fine with magento 2.2.4

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56230574/magento-2-order-emails-are-not-generated